# Scanning and Printing strings using an array of strings

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, scanf, c-strings

I've created an array of pointers each of which points to a string as follows.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char *str[4];
    for(int i = 0; i<4; i++)
    {
        scanf("%10s", str[i]);
    }
    puts(""); // not really required
    for(int i = 0; i<4; i++)
    {
        printf("%s\t", str[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

When I ran it, it compiled successfully. However, when I entered a string, it gave a segmentation fault. Can anyone help with this?

This is what I get when I run the code:

hello (what I input)
Segmentation fault (I get this immediately after hitting enter)

Comment: You have an array of pointers, but you never make them point anywhere. The pointers will have *indeterminate* values, and any attempt to dereference them will lead to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: The simplest solution to your problem, is to create an array *of arrays* instead; `char str[4][11];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
char *str[4];
```

This declares an array[4] of pointers to `char` whose contents are indeterminate, i.e. they do not point to anything meaningful, and dereferencing them would invoke undefined behavior.

You have to allocate memory for the pointers like so:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX_STR_SIZE 11

for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof str / sizeof *str; ++i) {
    str[i] = malloc(MAX_STR_SIZE);

    if (!str[i]) {
        /* Free the previous allocated memory and exit. */
        for (size_t j = i ? i - 1 : i; j >= 0; --j) {
            free(str[j]);
        }
        
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
}
```

Note that `malloc()` returns a null pointer to indicate failure, and the returned pointer must be later passed to `free()` when the memory is no longer required.

Or, you could forego dynamically allocating memory and use an array of arrays:

```
char str[4][11];
```

Also note that `scanf()` returns the number of conversions successfully performed, so its result should also be checked:

```
if (scanf("%10s", str[i]) != 1) {
    fputs(/* Error message here. */, stderr);
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```

And you can use `putchar('\n')` to print a newline instead of calling `puts()` with an empty string.

Comment: @Fe2O3 Fixed. Thank you.

Comment: Consider: `while( i-- ) free( str[ i ] );` as a simpler alternative... Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You created an uninitialized array of pointers

```
char *str[4];
```

elements of which has indeterminate values.

As a result using these pointers to access memory as for example in this call of scanf

```
scanf("%10s", str[i]);
```

invokes undefined behavior.

Instead of the array of pointers you could define a two-dimensional character array.

Here is a demonstratove program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void ) 
{
    enum { M = 4, N = 11 };
    char str[M][N];

    size_t n = 0;

    while ( n < M && scanf("%10s", str[n] ) == 1 ) ++n;

    putchar( '\n' );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        printf( "%s\t", str[i] );
    }

    putchar( '\n' );

    return 0;
}
```

Pay attention to that according to the C Standard the function `main` without parameters shall be declared like

```
int main( void )
```

Comment: @Harith Oh, you are right. It was a typo.:)